# Retrieving multiple records in different tables in same database

Tags: mysql

I have a small database that consists of two tables. I want to retrieve multiple records from those two tables, e.g.:

```
Table 01 -complaint_details - complaint_details_id(PK) 
Table 02 - Nature_Complaint - complain_no (PK)
DB name -gis
```

I want to retrieve complaint_details_id, district,from table 01 and Nature field from Nature_of_Complaint table.

I wrote the query as follows but it generate some errors:

```
SELECT complaint_details_id,district 
FROM gis.complaint_details INNER JOIN nature FROM nature_complaint 
WHERE
    gis.complaint_details.complaint_details_id=gis.nature_complaint.complain_no;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how your query should look like :

```
SELECT complaint_details.complaint_details_id,
       complaint_details.district,
       nature_complaint.nature
FROM gis.complaint_details 
INNER JOIN gis.nature_complaint 
 ON(complaint_details.complaint_details_id=nature_complaint.complain_no)
```

- The fields you want as an output should be specified in the `SELECT` clause.
- INNER JOIN is used with the `ON` clause, and not the `WHERE` clause .
- Use aliases to make the code cleaner and clearer .

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT cd.complaint_details_id, cd.district, nc.nature
FROM complaint_details cd JOIN Nature_Complaint nc 
     ON cd.complaint_details_id = nc.complain_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the second FROM .
remember  everytime you do a JOIN you have to set  a ON value

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

```
SELECT complaint_details_id,district,nature_complaint.nature FROM gis.complaint_details  INNER JOIN gis.nature_complaint ON(complaint_details.complaint_details_id=nature_complaint.complain_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a foreign key to one of the tables for it to work correctly.

```
    SELECT complaint_details_id,district,nature_complaint.nature
    FROM gis.complaint_details 
    JOIN gis.nature_complaint 
    ON(complaint_details.complaint_details_id=nature_complaint.complain_FK)
```

Join the primary key (complaint_details.complaint_details_id) with whatever you add the foreign key as in nature_complaint.complain